# React Native cuts off last word in line, but it needs to remove the entire word if it doesn't fit

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'd like the last element in this image to be removed, but so far I can only get it to be cut off.

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "nowrap", overflow: "hidden" }}>
  {item.sortedTagObjects.map(({ tag, color }) => (
    <Text
      key={tag}
      style={{
        height: 24,
        lineHeight: 24,
        paddingHorizontal: 8,
        paddingVertical: 2,
        justifyContent: "center",
        textAlign: "center",
        backgroundColor: "purple",
      }}
    >
      {tag}
    </Text>
  ))}
</View>;
```

When I try to make the wrapper `<Text numberOfLines={1}>` it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add a `ScrollView` as `Horizontal` to let it becomes more flexible?

Answer (score 2):

a quick solution would be for you to change your parent view to have a `maxHeight:24` or `height: 24`, just like your text, and change your flexWrap to `flexWrap: 'wrap'` instead of `nowrap`.

This will allow you to only render 1 row, and hide all the wrapped items on the other rows.

aka -

```
<View style={{ maxHeight: 24, flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap", overflow: "hidden" }}>
  {item.sortedTagObjects.map(({ tag, color }) => (
    <Text
      key={tag}
      style={{
        height: 24,
        lineHeight: 24,
        paddingHorizontal: 8,
        paddingVertical: 2,
        justifyContent: "center",
        textAlign: "center",
        backgroundColor: "purple",
      }}
    >
      {tag}
    </Text>
  ))}
</View>;
```